# Is there evidence for the Khazars as a naval nation?

Tags: steppe-nomads

From various reading through the years I understand that up to this day, the Caspian sea is often named "the Khazar sea" in some languages and maps: Persian, Azerbiajani, Turkmen and Turkish.

The very coinage of such a term, would imply, in my humble opinion, that the Khazars were a naval power inhabiting the northwestern, northcentral and northeastern part of that sea.

Is there evidence for the Khazars as a naval nation? Where Khazars, which where known as seasoned merchants, held and operated numerous trade ships? Perhaps some ships they might have built are still sunk in the bottom of the Caspian/Khazar sea to this day.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: "coinage of such a term, would imply, in my humble opinion, that "..   Alternatively it could imply "the sea round which a bunch of Khazar's live", or "the sea where the mapmaker first heard about Khazars".  The thesis you're advancing requires more research.